# Kubuntu 20.04 Screen Edges Preview/Selection broken

Tags: kubuntu, kde, settings, plasma

I'm trying to remove the top-left corner screen edge action, however when I launch the Screen Edges settings window in any way (main settings app, through the search box, using `kcmshell5 kwinscreenedges` from the terminal) the settings window comes up and looks like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, this means that I can't configure/disable individual corner actions.

I tried resetting the desktop scaling back to 100% thinking that it was the scaling that was messing with it, however that didn't help at all.

I found [an old Reddit post from 2018](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9ns84w/active_screen_corners_and_edges_settings_is_broken/) with a screenshot very similar to mine, but no solution there. All other posts assume that this window opens up normally.

Versions:

- Ubuntu: 20.04.2
- KDE Plasma: 5.18.5
- KDE Frameworks: 5.68.0
- Qt: 5.12.8
- Kernel: 5.4.0-27-generic

Ideally I'd prefer to find a fix for the settings screen, however some way to disable the top-left corner hot zone is truly what I'm after.